# Script to remove image orientation

Tags: automator, automation, image-editing, exif

I need to remove the orientation "flag" of a batch of images (jpeg images), without changing the displayed orientation of the images.

Trying to make it clear : if I have an image in portrait orientation with an orientation flag, I want it to keep this portrait orientation, but get rid of the orientation flag, as it seems some application are not able to handle it correctly. It's a kind of fusionning the image with its orientation flag.

I guess this means recompressing the image, but that is not a problem.

I tried to do it with automator, but was not able to do it. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Can't offer an `Automator script` but `Jhead` which is a command line Jpeg header manipulation tool.

1. Download [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/os-x/jhead)
2. Start `Terminal.app` and move the file to `/usr/local/bin/` with

   ```
   sudo mv ~/Downloads/jhead /usr/local/bin/jhead
   ```

   and enter your password
3. Make it executable `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/jhead`
4. Entering `jhead -v -norot ~/Pictures/folder/subfolder/*.jpg` should do the job and clears the Exif header rotation tag without altering the image.

Here is the [manual](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/usage.html). Make a test with some pictures in a subfolder before you rot your original pictures.